# Error while Trying to update an Oracle nested table

Tags: sql, oracle, oop, collections

I am trying to update some fields in oracle nested table, so I can insert some values, the problem is I am unable to retrieve the results as **nested table**. The following is the query I am trying to run:

```sql
update utilisation_obj
set listerefaccess = (
    select ref(a)
    from refaccessoireimb a
    where a.refaccessoire.accessoire in ('ballon', 'barre')
)
where  deref(utilisation_obj.REFTITREDENUM).titreDeNumero = 'Les Zoupalas' and 
deref(utilisation_obj.REFUTILISATEUR).nom = 'Louis';
```

The error is the following:

> inconsistent datatypes: expected CIRQUEOR.LISTEREFACCESS_T got : REF CIRQUEOR.REFACCESSOIRE_T

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution but I was hoping for a more dynamic solution since this one would force me to know what rows I expect to have

```sql
INSERT INTO Utilisation_Obj
Select Ref(N), Ref(P), ListeRefAccess_T(RefAccessoire_T(ref(A1)),RefAccessoire_T(ref(A2)))
From Numeros_Obj N, Personnel_Obj P, Accessoire_Obj A1,Accessoire_Obj A2
Where N.TitreDeNumero = 'Les Zoupalas' and P.Nom = 'Louis' and
A1.accessoire = 'ballon' and A2.accessoire = 'barre';
```